# How does Baby listen to Doc's plan if he has his headphones on?

Tags: character, baby-driver

In *Baby Driver*, The music that he listens to can be heard in the vicinity so it is safe to say that he is not putting his headphones on for show. How does he recite the plan perfectly when Doc instructs him to?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

That scene includes a close-up of Doc's lips, from Baby's perspective -- suggesting *Baby reads lips*.

Comment: The other clue that Baby is lip-reading is when Doc, who knows his quirks, says "I need four pairs of eyes and three pairs of ears"